# Where does the Tokaido Shinkansen stop in Tokyo?

Tags: japan, tokyo, japan-rail, shinkansen

I'm planning on taking the [Nozomi category of the Tokaido shinkansen](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2018_tokaido.html) from Osaka to Tokyo. I'm trying to figure out where exactly in Tokyo it stops. As best I can tell from Googling it stops in [Tokyo Station](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Tokyo+Station/@35.6713538,139.7417744,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x60188bfbd89f700b:0x277c49ba34ed38!8m2!3d35.6812981!4d139.7662479), but I haven't been able to get definitive confirmation of that and I know that Tokyo has a lot of train stations.

Can someone please confirm this?

Comment: It stops in quite a few places that you can choose to get off at.  Where are you hoping to end up?

Comment: @MarkMayo Narita International Airport.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Tokaido Shinkansen, Shinagawa station and Tokyo station are the two only stations in Tokyo.

You might comfirm this from the [offical timetable](http://english.jr-central.co.jp/info/timetable/).

Comment: Note that you can transfer to the Narita Express (JR's fastest service to Narita Airport) at either the Shinagawa or Tokyo stop.  Odds are that the Shinagawa transfer might be slightly cheaper; but, take a few more minutes to travel.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the given link does not answer the question since it does not state that Tokyo and Shinagawa stations are located in Tokyo, nor that no other station on the Tokaido Shinkansen is. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokaido_shinkansen#Stations) is a better reference.

Answer (score 8):

Tokaido Shinkansen trains stops at Tokyo Station (東京駅) in Chiyoda and Shinagawa Station (品川駅) in Minato.

Both stations are accessible by the major urban JR line of Tokyo, the Yamanote Line; Tokyo Station is also accessible by the Marunochi Line of the Tokyo Metro.

Also, both stations have direct JR train service to NRT. The JR East Narita Express Line is a limited express service from Omiya Station/Ofuna Station to NRT (Narita Airport Terminal 1 and Terminal 2/3 stations) - the cost is 3,020 yen from Tokyo to NRT and 3,190 yen from Shinagawa to NRT, but it is covered by a JR Pass if you own one. Please note, however, that Narita Express is a limited express, and all seats are reserved. You may do so [online](https://www.eki-net.com/pc/jreast-shinkansen-reservation/English/wb/common/Menu/Menu.aspx?_ga=1.75823701.1398596655.1482018354), or at a Midori-no-madoguchi (みどりの窓口) "green" ticket office at the Narita station.

Alternatively, you may take the rapid service train, Aiport Narita, which also serves the same route. It is slower (80-90 mins) than the limited express, but it is much cheaper: 1,490 yen from Shinagawa, 1,320 yen from Tokyo. Airport Narita is just an extended Sobu Express rapid service train, and no reservations will need to be made. However, if you take a JR train, be careful which train you board! Make sure the destination of the train is Narita Airport Terminal 1 Station (*Narita-kuko-eki yuki*)  You may also want to study the time table.

If you are at Shinagawa, you also have an extra option of taking a Keisei Electric Railway train. Although the Keisei Main Line doesn't go to Shinagawa, they operate a through service onto the Keikyu Main Line through the Toei Asakusa Line; Shinagawa Station is on the Keikyu Main Line. Thus, you could take a Keisei Main Line train if you go to the Keikyu part of the station. This will cost you 1,502 yen and around 80-90 minutes, so it's quite similar to the Sobu Express Airport Narita service in all respects. However, direct Keikyu trains from Shinagawa Sta. to NRT are infrequent; you may want to use the travel planner on [Keisei's website](http://www.keisei.co.jp/keisei/tetudou/skyliner/us/index.php) to plan your travel ahead of time (scroll down; it's at the bottom left).

Of course, you also have other options that involve transfers (e.g., transferring to Ueno and take the Keisei Skyliner there), which might also be worth considering. However, since I assume you are not familiar with Tokyo, I suggest you either:

- disembark at Shinagawa Station and take the Keikyu through train to Narita or the Sobu Express Line Airport Narita rapid service train, or:
- disembark at Tokyo and take the Narita Express.

I recommend the first; it's much cheaper. However, if you happen to have a JR Pass or don't have much time, take the second option.

Comment: As other have mentioned, there is Narita Express service from Shinagawa. Also, the direct Keikyu trains from Shinagawa to Narita are relatively infrequent, so one must carefully study the timetables if one plans to use them.

Comment: @fkraiem I said "there is through service to Shinagawa", meaning you can board a Narita Express train at Shinagawa Station although it is not on the Narita Express line. This is exactly what "through service" (直通運転) means. I'm aware that those direct Keikyu trains are infrequent; thanks for the note! I'll mention this.

Comment: The best (cheapest) option wih a JR pass is to take the suburban train (*Eapoto Narita*) from Tokyo Station. It leaves from the Sobu line platforms and takes 80-90 min

Comment: @Crazydre Yes, totally forgot about that...I just pulled out the JR East website; it tells me the ticket costs ￥1,490, which is close to the Keikyu train, but there are more Airport Narita express trains than there are Keikyu through service trains to Narita AFAIK. By the way, if I have a JR pass, I'd still take Narita Express: both are covered by the pass anyway, and the Narita Express takes 20-30 minutes less.

Comment: @XuanruiQi Huh, last time I checked the Express wasn't covered by the railpass

Comment: Now it is: http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/nex/tickets.html "JAPAN RAIL PASS or JR EAST PASS holders can make seat reservations without additional payment".

Comment: "The Narita Express line" does not exist. The Narita Express is a limited express service, which runs on several lines, such as the Sobu and Narita lines between Tokyo and Narita.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! While I know that there isn't a "Narita Express" line technically, I always thought it only goes to Tokyo and connects further by through service. Turns out I am wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Tokaido Shinkansen stops at Tokyo and Shinagawa stations. It also stops at Shin Yokohama station which is in Kanagawa prefecture, but very close to lots area of Tokyo.

If you are going to Narita, then Tokyo station definitely. Tokyo - Narita by Narita Express is less than a hour.

Furthermore if you want to travel cheaper and don't mind the extra 30 ~ 60 minutes (depending on the traffic), you can use the bus. For that you should go to Osaki (大崎) station which is 3 mins away from Shinagawa (品川) station. There you can take the bus. It will take you around 75 minutes (minimum) from Osaki to Narita (成田空港).

[image]

Comment: It's better to take the bus from tokyo station (1000 yen vs 1200 yen) I think. Also easier to find, no transfer, ...

Comment: @Antzi +1, link: http://honyaku.j-server.com/LUCKEISEIB/ns/tl.cgi/http://www.keiseibus.co.jp/kousoku/nrt16.html?SLANG=ja&TLANG=en&XMODE=0&XCHARSET=utf-8&XJSID=0#section_03